# sudo command not working in cron

Tags: sudo

I have a small script and I want to run it as user1 in cron. If I am logged in as user1 and execute the script it works just fine, but the moment I try to run it in cron it does not work. If I run the cron as root everything works. Here is what I am doing

Script has below command

```
sudo virsh list --all | grep myvm | awk '{print $3}'
running
```

So if I run it as user1 or put this into a file everything just works. But I add it as

```
*/5 * * * * user1 /path/to/script
```

If I run as root in cron it works smooth without sudo
    * * * * * root /path/to/script

My Sudoers file

```
Cmnd_Alias KVMCMD = /usr/bin/virsh list --all
%user1  ALL=(ROOT) NOPASSWD: KVMCMD
```

I directly cant blame sudoers as manually running the command works (may be because of tty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.

One of the solution would be

Editing (as root) the file

```
/etc/sudoers
```

And commenting out the line that says:

```
Defaults requiretty
```